# Glib: Calling a iterative loop function

Tags: multithreading, gtk, glib

Have a query on timeout calling and GMainContext. It is really confusing to me

Suppose I have the codes below (a bit incomplete, just for demonstration). I use normal Pthreads to create a thread. Within the thread, I run Glib functionality and created a GMainContext (stored within l_app.context).

I then created a source to run the function check_cmd iteratively at about 1 sec interval. This callback (or could we call it a thread?) will check for command from other threads( Pthreads not shown here for update in cmd status). From here onwards, there are two specific command

- One to start a looping function
- The other to end the looping function

I have done and thought of two ways to create the function and set them to run iteratively.

- To create another timeout
- using the same method of creating check_cmd

Essentially both to me are pretty much essentially the same method, when I tried both of them. Plan A (as I called it) does not work but Plan B ...actually run at least once. So I would like to know how to fix them...

Or maybe I should use g_source_add_child_source() instead?

In Summary, my question is

- when you created a new context and push it to become the default context, do all subsequent function that require main_context will refer to this context?
- in a nut shell, how do you add new sources when a loop is already running, ie like my cases
- lastly, it is okay to quit the main loop within the callback you have created?

Here is my pseudocode

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <pthread.h>

#define PLAN_A             0

typedef struct
 {
    GMainContext *context;
    GMainLoop *loop;
 }_App;


static _App l_app;
guint gID;

gboolean
time_cycle(gpointer udata)
{
    g_print("I AM THREADING");
    return true;
}

gboolean
check_cmd_session(NULL )
{
    while(alive)           /// alive is a boolean value that is shared with other threads(not shown)                     
    { 

        if(start)
        {
        /// PLAN A
        //// which context does this add to ??
#if PLAN_A
             g_timeout_add_seconds(10, (GSourceFunc)timeout, NULL);
#else
            /// or should i use PLAN B
            GSource* source = g_timeout_source_new(1000);

            gID = g_source_set_callback(source,
                            (GSourceFunc)time_cycle,
                            NULL,
                            NULL);

            g_source_attach(source, l_app.context);
#endif
        }
        else
        {
#if PLAN_A
            g_source_remove(gID);
#else           
        }

    }

    g_main_loop_quit (l_app.loop);
    return FALSE;
}



void*
liveService(Info *info)
{

    l_app.context = g_main_context_new ();
    g_main_context_push_thread_default(l_app.context);


    GSource* source = g_timeout_source_new(1000);

    g_source_set_callback(source,
                          (GSourceFunc)check_cmd_session,
                          NULL,
                          NULL);

    /// make it run
    g_source_attach(source, l_app.context);
    

    g_main_loop_run (l_app.loop);

    pthread_exit(NULL);

}



int main()
{
    pthread_t tid[2];

    int thread_counter = 0;
    err = pthread_create(&(tid[thread_counter]), NULL, &live, &info);
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf("\n can't create live thread :[%s]", strerror(err));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("--> Thread for Live created successfully\n");
        thread_counter++;
    }


    /**** other threads are build not shown here */

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        printf("Joining the %d threads \n", i);
        pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Summary, my question is
>
> 1. when you created a new context and push it to become the default context, do all subsequent function that require main_context will
>    refer to this context?

Functions that are documented as using the thread-default main context will use the `GMainContext` which has been most recently pushed with `g_main_context_push_thread_default()`.

Functions that are documented as using the *global* default main context will not. They will use the `GMainContext` which is created at init time and which is associated with the main thread.

`g_timeout_add_seconds()` is documented as using the *global* default main context. So you need to go with plan B if you want the timeout source to be attached to a specific `GMainContext`.

> 2. in a nut shell, how do you add new sources when a loop is already running, ie like my cases

`g_source_attach()` works when a main context is being iterated.

> 3. lastly, it is okay to quit the main loop within the callback you have created?

Yes, `g_main_loop_quit()` can be called at any point.

From your code, it looks like you’re not creating a new `GMainLoop` for each `GMainContext` and are instead assuming that one `GMainLoop` will somehow work with all `GMainContext`s in the process. That’s not correct. If you’re going to use `GMainLoop`, you need to create a new one for each `GMainContext` you create.

---

All other things aside, you might find it easier to use GLib’s threading functions rather than using pthread directly. GLib’s threading functions are portable to other platforms and a little bit easier to use. Given that you’re already linking to libglib, using them would cost nothing extra.